# All samples are concentrated in one part of the PCA scatter plot, how is that possible?

Tags: r, pca

I have an unusual result of a principal component analysis (PCA) that I am unsure how to explain or rationalise.

I seem to have component #1 sending all the samples in one direction of the plot without any going in the other direction. I was under the impression that this sort of distribution was not possible after PCA.

[image: PCA analysis of gene expression]

(The image was generated through the `mixOmics` package in R as `plotVar(pca(data))`. The data matrix has over 1000 rows so I cannot upload it here.)

Comment: Can you plot the original graph before transformation in the original axis?

Comment: Are you sure this is the component score plot and not the loading plot?

Comment: can you explain your question more?